# how to add additional arguments to RedirectPermanent?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to add a viewbag message to my return Action something like this....

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { Message = "Accepted Successfully" });
```

The above works fine, however I am trying to do the same on a tabbed Index view, which I discovered the only way to navigate back to the desired tab after post action is the following...

```
return RedirectPermanent("~/ReferralTarget/Index/#users");
```

Basically Index is the view and user is a tabbed view on the Index page...
Is there a way by which RedirectPermanaent will take a second argument ?
Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

if you must use `RedirectPermanent` there is no second argument, you can use `String.Format` to make the url

```
return RedirectPermanent(
 String.Format("~/ReferralTarget/Index/#users?Message={0}", "Message here"));
```

but you can use `RedirectToActionPermanent` to solve your problem